# MagnificPopup: associate an item inline at the corresponding element on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, magnific-popup

I have the following HTML code:

```
<section id="tm-section-3" class="tm-section tm-section-carousel">
                        <div>
                            <header class="mb-4"><h2 class="tm-text-shadow">Libri</h2></header>                 
                            <div class="tm-img-container">
                                <div class="tm-img-slider-2">
                                    <img src="img/book1.jpg" alt="Book1" class="img-fluid">
                                    <img src="img/book2.jpg" alt="Book2" class="img-fluid">
                                    <img src="img/book3.jpg" alt="Book3" class="img-fluid">
                                </div>
                            </div>                                    
                        </div>                          
                    </section>
```

And i initiatized the following magnificPopup:

```
// Init Magnific Popup
                $('.tm-img-slider-2').magnificPopup({
                    items: [
                      {
                        src: '<div class="container"><p><h4>Book 1</h4><p>This is book 1</p></div>',
                            type: 'inline'
                      },
                      {
                        src: '<div class="container"><p><h4>Book 2</h4><p>This is book 2</p></div>',
                        type: 'inline'
                       },
                      {
                        src: '<div class="container"><p><h4>Book 3</h4><p>This is book 3</p></div>',
                        type: 'inline'
                      }
                    ],
                    gallery: {
                      enabled: true,
                      navigateByImgClick: true
                    },
                });
```

The behavior that i would like is when i click the "Book 2" image element, on the Popup will appear immediately the item "This is book 2" (the second item), but actually when i click on any image element, will appear always "This is book 1", the first item (and i have to navigate always the gallery from arrows to show the desiderated element).

Comment: can you please make a working snippet?

Comment: https://codepen.io/bobc82/pen/bGwOjwR if you click on book2 or book3, book1 popup will appear.